# AutoDetectChangesEnabled is help to improve speed while reading large data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, query-performance

I have huge data in sql table and need to filter based on two columns using Entity framework. 
Would it be helpful if make tracking off as below OR read only operation does not impact while reading fields as below  ?
(to handle changes on code side, can't make any change on table).

```
///
try
{
 context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; 
var result = context.Logs.where(x=>x.refId == refId && x.name==name);
return await result.ToListAsyn();
}
finally
{
 context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; 
}
////
```

Comment: Use `context.Logs.AsNoTracking().Where(...)` instead.

Comment: `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` does not prevent tracking entity instances. Use no tracking queries as pointed out by @Evk, and additionally disable proxy creation (in case you have `virtual` navigation properties).

Comment: Ok. so, `AutoDetectChangesEnabled ` is context level to track off entities and applying at `.AsNoTracking` will be at entity level.